# Изменить стиль

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Всем привет! Необходима если нету iframe изменить стиль, а этот скрипт вставляет данные при  любых условиях.

```
<body id="sites">
<div id="mains">
<div class="border">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="texts">
<div id="content">                  
<div class="upBalance">
    <div class="headerO">
        <a href="http://xx.net/" class="logo" target="_blank"></a>      
        <div class="phone">
            test
            <span>68-000</span>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <h2 class="test">test</h2>
    <div class="balanceBox">
        <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="userSumm"><span>Сумма:</span><span  class="currency">руб.</span>
                <input type="text" name="amount" id="id_amount" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="userAccount"><span>Счет:</span>
                <input type="text" name="description" id="id_description" />
            </div>
            <div class="send"><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="comments"> 
        <p>test</p> 
        <p>test</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="footerO">
        <span> test</span>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
if(!$('.upBalance').parents('body').last().find('iframe').length)
$('.balanceBox').css({'margin': '0 auto'});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не могу въехать в вашу html-структуру. Получается, что вы для элемента с классом "**.upBalance**" получаете всех предков "**body**" (*у вас их несколько что ли?*), выбираете последний "**body**", в котором ищите элемент "**iframe**"? Как-то всё уж очень запутано. Может покажите часть структуры html, относящейся к данному коду?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, судя по вашему коду, тут ничего особенного делать не надо и [[@SilverIce](/users/2993/silverice)](/users/2993/silverice) как бы уже ответил на ваш вопрос. Могу только добавить еще несколько способов проверки для разнообразия ;)

```
// Вариант 1
if(!$('body').has('iframe').length){
}
// Вариант 2
if(!$('body').find('iframe').length){
}
```

Comment: А если на оборот убрать 'margin': '0 auto' если нет iframe?

Comment: Так добавьте **else**, делов то ... )))    if(!$('body').has('iframe').length){        // код, если нету    } else {        // код, если есть    }[Смотрим примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/r2HeC/1/)

Comment: >А если на оборот убрать 'margin': '0 auto'

Убрать 'margin' нельзя - его можно переопределить. Если нужно, что бы блок не центрировался - задайте значение "0".

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  if(!document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length){//чистый javascript отработает быстрее
    $('.balanceBox').css({'margin': '0 auto'});
  }
</script>
```

Если на странице нет "iframe" - меняем стиль блоку с классом "balanceBox".